# Uninstall Eclipse under OSX?

Tags: eclipse, macos, uninstallation

I'm running Eclipse SDK 3.4.0 on Mac OS X 10.5.6.

Every time I try to install something new through "software updates", the message "The software items you selected may not be valid with your current installation" shows up.

So I'm going to uninstall it and re-install Eclipse.

Should I just erase the Eclipse folder or is there a way to uninstall it?

Comment: To Eclipse developers. Please make your software uninstall cleanly! To Apple! Please sandbox apps on Mac OS!

Answer (score 69):

Actually Eclipse does create some other files not within it's directory which survive deleting it's directory.

In Snow Leopard, look in your user's account under:

- `~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.eclipse`
- `~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist`

Not sure if you need to turn on viewing of hidden files to see those.

Comment: those aren't installed files, those are cache files from when it runs. it's storing your preferences.

Comment: True, but semantic. Eclipse installs those files. Just a matter of opinion but to me uninstall means remove all traces of an application from the system.

Comment: There also may be a .eclipse directory in your home directory.

Comment: For what it's worth, my two Snow Leopard installations don't have this.

Comment: Why, in this day and age, is uninstallation so hard? For all the flack that Windows gets, at least it seems to have some understanding that uninstallation is a real thing, and more complicated than dragging some icon to the trash.

Comment: @Petey i yearn for the day when desktops sandbox their apps like mobile devices do

Answer (score 42):

Under Lion I deleted the following files and folders:

- **eclipse** in `/Applications` (obviously)
- **.eclipse** in `~`
- **.eclipse_keyring** in `~`
- **org.eclipse.eclipse** in `~/Library/Caches`
- **org.eclipse.eclipse.savedState** in ~/Library/Saved Application State/

Some of them are hidden so you should delete them via Terminal.

Comment: same under Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Comment: For what it's worth, my two Snow Leopard installations don't have anything in ~, or anything interesting in ~/Library.

Comment: also ~/Library/Saved Application State

Comment: also ~/Library/Preferences/

Answer (score 28):

Here is my list of things to delete for OSX Mountain Lion

~/.eclipse (folder);

~/Library/Saved Application/org.eclipse.eclipse.savedState;

~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist;

~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.eclipse;

... and of course the eclipse install folder

Answer (score 14):

No need to uninstall anything, you can just delete the eclipse/ folder, but you should also use a fresh workspace or delete the workspace/.metadata folder.

Comment: @Niels The folder you specified when you launched Eclipse for the first time, where your projects are stored.

Comment: Ahh ok, I thought it was an OSX folder like /Library.
Thanks!

Comment: After delete workspace in spot light still Eclipse showing (mac restarted)

Answer (score 6):

In my case with High Sierra, apart from the eclipse folder, I deleted also:

- ~/.eclipse
- ~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.*
- ~/.p2/pool/.eclipseextension/
- ~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/
- ~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/
- ~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/

Answer (score 5):

1. From terminal, find all eclipse directories with

   `sudo find / -iname "Eclipse"`
2. Delete those directories with `rm` command.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the eclipse folder is equivalent to uninstalling it. In fact, if you don't want to tamper with the existing installation you can create another instance of eclipse and run from the new location.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has no impact on Mac OS beyond it directory, so there is no problem uninstalling.

I think that What you are facing is the result of Eclipse switching the plugin distribution system recently. There are now two redundant and not very compatible means of installing plugins. It's a complete mess. You may be better off (if possible) installing a more recent version of Eclipse (maybe even the 3.5 milestones) as they seem to be more stable in that regard.

Comment: I believe this is the answer to my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396629/does-restoring-eclipse-from-timemachine-work (which was closed as OT for SO).

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is too old but recently I was wondering how to delete `eclipse` app on my `MacBook Pro` running `macOS High Sierra`.

Bellow are the steps which I followed to delete it from my system. Added screenshots for more clear understanding.

1. Open the eclipse app and it will show an app icon in dock. If it is not already present in dock then please try to run the app from `Spotlight Search` by pressing `⌘` + `space`.
2. Now right click on that eclipse logo from dock and click `Show in Finder` under `Options`.

[image]

3. It will open the location of the `eclipse` app in an external finder window.

[image]

4. You can just delete the entire root directory (i.e. - `eclipse`) by pressing `⌘` + `delete`.

[image]

5. Don't forget to delete the app from `Trash` as well if you are removing it from system completely.

Thanks. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

BTW. AppZapper is a great OSX tool for uninstalling apps and their preferences.

It sometimes comes a part of MacHeist

Answer (score 2):

For BigSur, I did follow considering all the above.

1. Remove from Applications folder
2. `rm -rf ~/.eclipse/`
3. `rm -rf ~/.p2/pool/`
4. `rm -rf ~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/`
5. `rm -rf ~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/`
6. `rm -rf ~/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/`
7. `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.platform.ide/`
8. `rm ~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.product.with-jre.restricted.plist`
9. `rm ~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.platform.ide.plist`
10. `rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.product.with-jre.restricted.savedState/`
11. `rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/org.eclipse.platform.ide.savedState/`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **eclipse** folder wherever it is

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, with the GWT-PlugIn not showing up in the interface.
Deleting the eclipse folder did not solve it, GWT was still there!
Deleting workspace didn't work!
But deleting the .eclipse folder in the home directory did!
I'm working under WIndows 7 here, but it should be the same with OSX. But you may have to make the folder visible first. Under linux based system, folders starting with a dot are invisible by default.

This folder was probably the reason I had problems in the first place. If I remember right, I switched from basic Eclipse to EE, but didn't delete this folder.

In my opinion, an uninstall skript would do Eclipse quite good.