# How to delete Eclipse completely (including settings and plugins) from Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, uninstallation

My Eclipse with GAE broken and works strangely.
So I deleted Eclipse from Application folder, but there is garbage left. I re-downloaded fresh new eclipse, but it runs with old settings, and broken GAE structure remained.

How can I DELETE completely Eclipse from my Mac? (without any kind of settings/plugins/logs etc.)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470261/uninstall-eclipse-under-osx/9043520

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Eclipse itself will be installed where you've unzipped the file you've downloaded. This directory contains `Eclipse.app`, `configuration/`, `plugins/` and `features/` (amongst others).

Your `workspace/` directory (in your home directory by default) contains all your projects and various settings too, in `workspace/.metadata/` (see dot files if you want to have a look). Deleting the workspace will delete your own project files of course, so you would need to make sure you have a way to restore them from a clean version (for example from a version control system if you're using one).

If you don't want to delete your entire workspace, it might be worth moving it away and then copying the projects back in, leaving the new `workspace/.metadata/` clean, to see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Additionally, remove `~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist` and `~/Library/Saved Application State/org.eclipse.eclipse.savedState`.

Comment: I don't know about Mac OSX, but on Linux I also had to `rm -rf ~/.p2 ~/.ecipse` to get rid of all the settings.

Answer (score 7):

Add ~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.platform.ide to the list

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As you said, once I have enough reputation, I can comment on others' posts. At the moment I don't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is the right place for such kind of questions...But r u using any applications such  as "app cleaner"?
if not try it... http://en.softonic.com/s/app-remover:mac