# Eclipse/Mac/Android: Deleting a project and recreating one with the same name

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm a complete newbie to Eclipse and Android development and I've been trying to delete a project and then creating one with the same name again. I choose to delete the project from the workspace and the dir/files are indeed gone. The new AndroidManifest.xml file though has the original contents appended as does the layout XML file and generates parsererrors rightaway!

Are references to the project file somehow stored outside the workspace dir itself that I can delete by hand?

If I restart Eclipse after deleting the project, it doesn't give me this problem

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a project from the eclipse it shows you following dialog box,

[image]

If you have selected(ticked) the option as shown in the image, it will delete all the files and folders of the project from the workspace. You can not get back once you delete it.  But if you haven't selected this option then it will only delete project from the project explorer/package explorer, but project files and folders are safe there in the workspace which you can later get it by importing in the eclipse.

Comment: Like I said, I did do this and I confirmed from Terminal that the files were gone indeed!

Answer (score -1):

Once you delete the project from the Workspace, in Windows it's at the User main Workspace/[The project] once you delete, your project goes to dream land. so you restart Esclipse and make new one with same name, thats not an issue.
Umm, try searching in your mac about the project name, or go to the workspace and delete it, it should be enough.

I found this, take a look at it, please:

[How to delete Eclipse completely (including settings and plugins) from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185664/how-to-delete-eclipse-completely-including-settings-and-plugins-from-mac-os-x/3185723#3185723)

Sorry, but you can delete Eclipse, and re-install it as a secondary option, if u deleted the Dir, and your project name is still in-use x.x

EDIT: in the link it says that you can change the workspace to another place, so I suggest you change the workspace place or delete the whole workspace after u take a backup of it.