# how to totally delete eclipse and start over (os x)?

Tags: eclipse

I've having some problems with my eclipse set-up, and I'm thinking of just deleting it and starting again from scratch. If I delete my workspace directory, and the eclipse.app from the applications folder, will that get everything, or are there some extra hidden files somewhere I have to worry about? I'm on OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninstall Eclipse under OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470261/uninstall-eclipse-under-osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the eclipse folder. That will be enough. You won't need to delete your workspace you can always create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

~/eclipse is an old directory. Nothing has changed in that directory for 3 years.
The new directory is ~/.eclipse.

However, I renamed ~/eclipse, ~/.eclipse, and ~/workspace, started up eclipse, and it still prompted me with the old workspace location!

Where is it getting that workspace name and location from?