# Mac OS-X Eclipse with Google App Engine setup: JDK version error when launching Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, google-app-engine, java-7

On my Mac OS-X Mavericks, I had the Eclipse Java Enterprise Ed Helios version with JRE 1.6 installed.

I updated my Eclipse version to Eclipse Kepler Java Enterprise Edition (Eclipse Kelpler v 4.3)

Then I installed Google App Engine components (Basically downloaded and install Google Pugin for Kepler ... from https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3)

When I started up the new Eclipse Kepler I got the following error (screenshot below) indicating my JRE (v 1.6) was out-of-date and I need version 1.7.0+

[image]

So I downloaded the latest JDK v 1.8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

I installed this with  step by step instructions from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html

I set the SDK version in Eclipse by going to Preferences->Java->Installed JREs (and navigating to the folder containing the new JRE)

However when I restart Eclipse I still get the same error ie (JRE needs to be 1.7.0 or above)

**** Any ideas what setting I am missing or what else I need to set? ****

Here's a running log and screenshots of things I have tried:

Screenshots of latest system preference (java) settings and Eclipse java preferences:

[image]

[image]

And here are the contents of eclipse.ini

```
-startup ../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

UPDATE:
I edited my eclipse.ini to ensure that the -vm specification for jvm 1.7 was across two lines as suggested by @manouti

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
```

And now when I start eclipse the get this different error. Checking online it appears I need to add some capabilities to the JVM init file ....

[image]

I checked the following blog http://burrsutter.blogspot.com/2013/12/eclipse-does-not-contain.html and per recommendations posted there, I updated the capabilities section of my JVM 7 info.plist file as follows:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
      <array>
            <string>CommandLine</string>
            <string>JNI</string>
            <string>BundleApp</string>
            <string>WebStart</string>
            <string>Applet</string>
      </array>
```

That blog also recommends a different value for the -vm option in the eclipse.ini  ...

Also set the java version to 1.7 at startup, by adding the following line to ~/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

Still get the capabilities error above "does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol"

I tried changing the -vm line in eclipse.ini to that recommended in burrsutter's blog http://burrsutter.blogspot.com/2013/12/eclipse-does-not-contain.html i.e. set -vm in eclipse.ini to:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

With this I continue to get the capabilities error shown above ...

also tried

```
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java
```

... With this  the original error comes back i.e. "JRE version is 1.6.0 version 1.7.0 or later is needed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial impetus for this procedure came from @manouti (thank you!) but I've added all the steps needed for a newbie to integrate app engine with Eclipse on a Mac OSCX Mavericks. Here is the step by step solution:

- Ensure that you have Java version 1.7 installed on your Mac OSX Mavericks:

download the JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Step by step instuctions to download and install JDK 1.7 are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html

Edit in terminal vi ~/.bash_profile and add the following line:
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`

Reboot your Mac.

- Next ensure that you have Eclipse_kepler.

check version on mac. Current Mac Pros have the 64 bit version ….
(in terminal type:  ‘uname -a’  if you see ‘RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64’ it means you have the 64 bit version)

Delete whatever versons of eclipse you have.
- delete everything that has org.eclipse in its name from folders ~/Library/Saved Application State, ~/Library/Preferences and ~/Library/Caches and then delete the eclipse folder (ensure that you copy your Workspaces folder to a safe place before you do this)

Update Eclipse to version Eclipse EE Kepler for Mac 64 bit by downloading from
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

When you start up Eclipse you will notice that the Java settings in Kepler are set to default 1.7

- Download and install Google Pugin for Kepler (use instructions at
  https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3)

(Use the eclipse software update feature and type in URL:
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3)
Just install Google Plugin for Eclipse.

- Now you are all set to begin the tutorial Steps to Integrate XCode/iOS with Google
  App Engine

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the new JDK is set in your CLASSPATH and PATH environment variables. Eclipse may still be using the old JDK1.6. You can call `java -version` to check the default version used on your machine. Also make sure that the eclipse.ini file in your Eclipse installation directory does not launch using JDK1.6. You can edit eclipse.ini so that it launches using JDK1.8:

```
-vm
/path/to/java1_8
```

Comment: Thanks - when I do java -version I get

java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)


However when I check eclipse.ini I see ...
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 

I can try changing that to -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

Comment: That did not work either ... I now get an error "Version 1.6.0_05 is not suitable for this product. Version 1.8 or greater is required"

Comment: Should that be ...?

"-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java"

Comment: Tried that and it gives me the error in the screenshot

Comment: You shouldn't change the -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion parameter. Also you may find this post useful: http://rshankar.com/java-version-1-7-required-to-google-plugin-on-eclipse/. If even after the -vm option change it doesn't work, then maybe you should consider removing the old JDK.

Comment: Followed all the steps in that rshankar.com document (it helped get me the 1.7 jdk as from oracle I had used the latest i.e. 1.8) Made all changes step by step including updates to eclipse.ini and ensuring that I did check-for-updates in eclpise.... but ....still no luck wih that error popup. I'll try removing the old JDKs (I imagine I will need to do that only in eclipse or are you suggesting I remove them from the Java console/and from my Mac OS as well)?

Comment: This is weird since pointing to the new vm in eclipse.ini should tell Eclipse to launch with that VM. Worst case try removing all old JDKs/JREs on your machine and have a clean install of the newest JDK and JRE with the PATH and CLASSPATH set to the new JDK.

Comment: Tried all that including the remove commands for previous jdks. I ran the command "sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.{8.6}*" to remove JDK's 1.6 and 1.8 and replace them with JDK 1.7. Have attached screenshots of the Java console settings (shows only JDK 8, and the Eclipse preferences java settings (where I have set JDK 7 and default and removed JDK 8)It's quite a mess now -

Comment: Tryin to find a methodical step-by-step clean up my Java environment across the Mac (system) settings and XCode settings but ...... there does not appear to be a methodical step by step procedure for this (what I have tried so far is not working so trying to develop one as I go).

Comment: In summary: (1) I had java sdk 1.6 installed. (2) After installed Google Appengine sdk, Eclipse on startup complains that I'm running JRE 1.6 and I need 1.7 or above for Google App Engine (see popoup above) (3) So I installed the latest i.e. 1.8 but that did not work (same error) (4) I then installed jdk 1.7  and set it as default in XCode preferences to see if that would work - it did not. (5) I tried removing jdk's 1.6 and 1.8 (ran in terminal the command "rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.{8.6}*" but I still get the same error.

Comment: Screen shots of my java settings on mac system console and eclipse preferences are attached above.

Comment: Would you mind attaching your eclipse.ini? The vm argument should be set to point to the 1.7 or 1.8 JVM (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example). Also from the Eclipse screenshot, I'm still seeing a reference to the 1.6 JDK.

Comment: manouti  I truly appreciate you sticking with this question. I just added the eclipse.ini contents in my question-post above (see at end)

Comment: I don't know about the folder structure of the JDK on Mac OS but could it be a wrong path in the -vm option? Maybe it should not end with libjvm.dylib? Also maybe the path should on a new line (the -vm should be on one line then the path on a new line) (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example shows an example for Mac)

Comment: thank you I split up the line as you suggested (see above updated issue description) and now I receive a missing symbol alert. Checking  this Blog where the writer appears to have encountered a similar issue ...

http://burrsutter.blogspot.com/2013/12/eclipse-does-not-contain.html

Comment: Made several changes as logged above. Tried setting the JAVA_HOME in ~/.bash_profile and updated the -vm options as per your suggestions and the one in the blog. Still get the errors (have updated the text of the issue with the error messages I got at each of these attempts)

Comment: Now that the java version is set, I will try to delete and reinstall eclipse kepler

Comment: I deleted eclipse as follows:(a) removed the eclipse_kepler folder (b) removed other extraneous folders listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470261/uninstall-eclipse-under-osx/9043520 and then downloaded a fresh version of kepler. Realized I had previously downloaded the 32 bit version of kepler whereas my mac is 64 bit (can tell by doing a 'uname -a' in a terminal shell) Will try this now - i.e. will download/install app engine (and keeping the java at the latest version 1.8 settings)

Comment: Yep that fixed it! I installed Eclipse-kepler 64 bit version and set JDK to version 1.7 in ~/.bash_profile and then installed the google_plugin in eclipse update

Comment: Good news finally! Yes it was probably due to the 32-bit Eclipse. It seems it was still using 32-bit old JRE.