# Cannot Install Google plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I am not able to install the Google plugin for Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 on Mac. I followed all the steps, and got no errors.

Eclipse restarted after installing the plugin, but after that I don't see the Google logo on my  toolbar and even in File > New, I don't see any signs of installation.

Android plugins from the same link seems to be working but rest no sign.

Java on my Mac is up to date.

Comment: [I don't see any installations](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started) for Eclipse Luna 4.4.1...maybe that's what's up?

Comment: Could be but android plugins from the same link seems to be working.

Comment: I tried trashing JUNO and installed Kepler. Re did all the steps, but still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 6 long hours, it worked out for me. This is what I did

1. I removed eclipse from my computer. delete those file from library folder. Delete workstation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1998797/3861959
2. Updated Java, Downloaded and installed latest version of JDK (its different from java, one thing I didn't know).
3. Installed Eclipse, installed plugin