# Google plugin for Eclipse Luna not showing the icon

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, scripting

I have been around 4 hours trying to install the Google Plugin for Eclipse Luna. I followed every step of [the installing guide](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download) but when i finished the Google Logo for starting a new project didnt appear as it should:

[image: like this]

As you can see even though i have the plugins installed i cant see the icon or start a new web project.

[image]

My operating sysyem is OSx Yosemite. I tried updating to Java 8 and JDK 8 (and 7) and deleting all the files as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884485/cannot-install-google-plugin-for-eclipse) recommends. Also deleted and "reinstalled" eclipse and the plugin a lot of times but didn't workout.

Anybody with the same problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i also have this problem... any solution?

Comment: Im still looking for any help .. to be honest i gave up and im using the Google Scripts platform. Did you find and answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on my new MacBook. I had to install JDK 7. I downloaded and installed the Mac OS X x64 version of 7u75 from here:
[JDK 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

After it installs make sure it's the system default by executing the following from the Terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

If it looks good to go then just restart eclipse and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you even to delete your Eclipse_Luna:

Re-install your Eclipse and then install the GAE-plugin again.

Remember to re-start your Eclipse after you've successfully install the GAE-plugin for Eclipse_Luna.

Comment: Hi @Jun-L thanks for the answer but as i said on the description y tried re-installing a lot of times but it didn't help out.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I installed JDK 1.7 and used 1.7 jre for eclipse as mapped and downloaded the eclpise plugin AND restarted and it worked fine.