# How to solve Mac Eclipse fail to install or open after change of username/user directory name on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, installation

I changed my username because some reason(actually for install hadoop), and cannot open eclipse.

Java 1.8 works well

Install fail with internal error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself, because I didn't find answer from stackOverflow, I wish to share my solution to you guys who have the same issue occur.

1. Finder or Terminal go to ~, namely the username directory
2. delete the directory called .eclipse under username directory
3. restart

This is because eclipse stored a username as meta-data in this directory, if you didn't

delete this directory, eclipse will not get the right path to install or launch.

If this does not work, try @j7nn7k's answer in this post, then repeat step3.
[j7nn7k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9043520/5686376)

Just reminder.

Even unsuccessful installation will create a new directory.